# Limiting gnuplot plot of huge binary data file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I've been given a huge 9GB binary data file (format is '%float%float'), and gnuplot 5.0 goes belly-up when it tries to read the entire thing.

How can I formulate a plot command to limit the plot so it reads only 1K or 2K or so of the binary data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use gnuplot's [every](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node121.html) keyword, for example to plot the first 2000 records:

```
plot 'file.dat' binary format='%float%float' every ::::2000 using 1:2 with lines;
```

but it seems like that reads the whole file in and then plots only the first 2000 records, which is probably not what you want. So you might have to use an external utility, like:

```
plot "<(head --bytes 16000 file.dat)" binary format='%float%float' using 1:2 with lines
```

For example this toy test worked for me:

```
perl -e 'for ($i=0; $i < 21; $i++) { print pack "ff", $i, $i*$i }' > squares.dat
gnuplot -e "set terminal png;set out 'only5squares.png';plot '<(head --bytes 40 squares.dat)' binary format='%float%float' using 1:2 with lines;"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, your first suggestion does read through the entire data file. The second results in a gnuplot warning: Skipping data file with no valid points. An empty plot results. I'm not sure gnuplot knows the concept of 'record' when it's binary data?

Comment: Hmm, a toy example (I edited the answer to add it) worked for me with gnuplot 5.0.

Comment: There are other keywords that could be used with `binary` that modify gnuplot's concept of a "record", though, like `filetype` and `array`, in case you are using one of those.

Comment: That's getting closer! But gnuplot still complains when I use this cmd: `gnuplot -e "set terminal png; set xrange [0.00:2.0]; set yrange [0.3:2.0]; set out 'only5squares.png';plot '<(head --bytes 40 squares.dat)' binary format='%float%float' using 1:2 with lines;"`  Errors: `head: illegal option -- -
usage: head [-n lines | -c bytes] [file ...]
line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points` I'm using gnuplot V5.0.6

Comment: Oops, I incorrectly assumed you were using the Linux version of `head`, which honors the `--bytes` option. Since yours seems to advertise `-c bytes`, what about replacing `head --bytes 16000` with `head -c 16000`?

Comment: So I use `'<(head -c 40 squares.dat)'` syntax and it accepts it. Now to try it on the huge data file...

Comment: Perfect! Yes, that does the trick! Here's the final gnuplot command I used: `plot '<(head -c 4000 dualfloat.dat)' binary format='%float%float' using 1:2 with lines`